# Can't access ArrayList HashMap values in AsyncTask

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, hashmap

I have an `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` in `AsyncTask` that I want to store data retrieved from database into it and then I want to access each element of my list in `onPostExecute`, but I have error in getting values from arraylist. I have a log in my code which PID tag , but in logcat I can't see it.

```
class Search extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    int success ;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... args) {


        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("search", result));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://timit.ir/search/query1",
                "POST", param);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());


        // check for success tag
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);


                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);



                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String bname = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String success = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    String subname = c.getString(TAG_SUBNAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, bname);
                    map.put(TAG_SUCCESS, success);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBNAME, subname);


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
                Log.d("PID:", productsList.get(0).get(TAG_PID));

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return productsList;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {


        Log.d("succeeeeeeeeeessssss:::", result.get(0).get(TAG_SUCCESS));
        if(result.get(0).get(TAG_SUCCESS) !=null && result.get(0).get(TAG_SUCCESS).equals("1")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ok", 2000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "fail", 2000).show();
        }


    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
  D/Create Response(3355): {"product":[{"Pro_Details":"kjhkh","Pro_Subname":"kjhkh","Pro_Name":"kjkhkj","Pro_ID":"16"}],"success":1}
  W/dalvikvm(3355): threadid=36: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at com.example.timittest.MainActivity$Search.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:478)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at com.example.timittest.MainActivity$Search.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  E/AndroidRuntime(3355):   ... 4 more
```

Comment: I'll hazard a guess that productsList is null

Comment: productsList.add(map)

Comment: may this line gives Null pointer exception productsList.add(map);

Comment: i gave log from each items id, name ,... and all of them ok!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is you are getting success object in product array but it is another object

JSON:
"product":[],
"success" :" 1"

remove this line from your code:

```
 String success = json.getString(TAG_SUCCESS)`;
```